# HybridAuth session variable issue

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, flickr, hybridauth

I'm trying to create a Flickr provider for the [HybridAuth library](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) in order to authenticate users, but am running into an issue.

I'm using the [Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/), which is based on OAuth 1.

The problem is that the API calls I'm interested in need to specify a username or user id, regardless of whether or not the user is currently authenticated.

Although inconvenient, this should be fine, since upon reception of an access token during authentication, the Flickr API returns both the username and user_nsid (http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html, see "Exchanging the Request Token for an Access Token").

However, HybridAuth didn't seem to store these pieces of information in the `$adapter` variable during authentication. I dug into the code, and found that **they are** in fact stored. A quick `var_dump` after the following lines in the `loginFinish()` function of `Provider_Model_OAuth1.php` shows that they are indeed stored in `$this->access_raw_tokens` (`$this` being identical to `$adapter`):

```
// request an access token
$tokens = $this->api->accessToken( $oauth_verifier );

// access tokens as received from provider
$this->access_tokens_raw = $tokens;
```

So far so good. But then, I try to call the Flickr adapter on a custom page:

```
try{
    // initialize Hybrid_Auth with a given file
    $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth($config);
    $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate("Flickr");
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

The code executes fine, but when I try `var_dump($adapter);` the `access_tokens_raw` field is set as `access_tokens_raw = null`.

If need be, I can provide my Flickr provider code (`Flickr.php`), which is almost identical to `Twitter.php` when it comes to `initialize()` and `loginBegin()`.

This issue has been bugging me for a while, and I'd greatly appreciate your input! I welcome any solution that would allow me to retain the authenticated Flickr username or user_nsid without compromising the HybridAuth authentication of other providers.

Comment: did you get it at last ? I have the same problem !

Comment: Hey @FlamingMoe! I'm no longer maintaining the code that I wrote, but I believe that I resorted to a *hackish* approach of storing the `access_tokens_raw` property in a new session variable (e.g. `$_SESSION['flick_user_nsid'] = $this->access_tokens_raw;`) in the `Flickr.php` provider before its value is destroyed, then retrieving the value from the session variable once the adapter has been initialized.

That being said, I do believe the Flickr API has changed since, so I am unsure if it still uses OAuth1, or if the user_nsid is even needed for subsequent API calls.

Good luck!